# How can I make a component 'extend' the prop types of another?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I've made a wrapper component like this:

```
import WrappedComponent from 'some/external/typed/library'

interface ComponentProps { name: 'foo' | 'bar' }

function Component({ name, ...props}: ComponentProps) {
  return <WrappedComponent foobar={name} {...props} />
}
```

But now someone who wants to know what props Component accepts thinks it only accepts a 'name' prop when in reality it accepts all the props that WrappedComponent accepts PLUS the name prop.

How can I change ComponentProps to say "I accept everything WrappedComponent accepts and also 'name'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use [Intersection Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) like this:

```
function Component({ name, ...props}: ComponentProps & React.ComponentProps<typeof WrappedComponent>) {
   return <WrappedComponent foobar={name} {...props} />
}
```

If you are using typescript, otherwise you have to import the interface that defines the props of WrappedComponent and then use it as:

```
interface ComponentProps extends WrappedComponentProps { name: 'foo' | 'bar' }
```

Comment: Your first answer had me super excited, but I dont think it works. 

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-6mgpmv?file=/src/App.tsx

You can see the typescript error on line 20 under the yesno property

Comment: I was almost there, React has their own wrapper for extracting props from functional components. This should achieve what you wanted https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-nt0bki